# Is this new ES6 feature?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am learning React Native but do not understand some syntax used in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#content

```
 _pressData: ({}: {[key: number]: boolean}),

_genRows: function(pressData: {[key: number]: boolean}): Array<string> {
```

I tried to check if it is new ES6 feature but no luck. I would appreciate if someone can give me a reference to that syntax or explain it here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing there is type annotations for Flow, which is a static type checker. Read more about that here! http://flowtype.org/

Answer (score 1):

For quick reference:
http://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html#_

> Objects as Maps
>
> An object can be viewed as a map from string to some value type by setting and getting its properties via bracket notation (i.e. dynamic accessors), instead of dot notation. Flow infers a precise value type for the map: in other words, if you only write number values to a map, you will read numbervalues back (rather than, say, any).
>
> Such a map can be given a type of the form { [key: string]: number } where string is the key type and number is the value type of the map.